# Laravel eloquents belongsto

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I've got a problem on my view using Laravel 4.1. I did a relation oneToMany between two tables. When I put this code in my view, I don't have any problem:

```
{{ $admin->admin_role()->first()->name }}
```

But when I tried to put it shorter as the [laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) said like this:

```
{{ $admin->admin_role->name }}
```

I've a got

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I know it's not a big problem as I can use the first option, but if someone got any ideas, I would love to read them!

Thanks everyone

Comment: Is the one-to-many relation one admin has many roles, or does 1 role have many admins?

Comment: in my project, 1 role has many admins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my project, 1 role has many admins

If one role has many users then it'll return a collection even if there is only one `admin` so following code returns a collection of `models` and you can't get any property from a collection without specifying the model:

```
$admin->admin_role();
```

So you may use (already know that):

```
$admin->admin_role()->first()->name;
$admin->admin_role()->last()->name;
$admin->admin_role()->find(1)->name; // Assumed 1 is id (primary key)
$admin->admin_role()->get(0); // it's first, equivalent to first()
$admin->admin_role()->get(1); // second item from collection
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code when you use model instance's getter.

https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L2249

```
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    $inAttributes = array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes);

    // If the key references an attribute, we can just go ahead and return the
    // plain attribute value from the model. This allows every attribute to
    // be dynamically accessed through the _get method without accessors.
    if ($inAttributes || $this->hasGetMutator($key))
    {
        return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
    }

    // If the key already exists in the relationships array, it just means the
    // relationship has already been loaded, so we'll just return it out of
    // here because there is no need to query within the relations twice.
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->relations))
    {
        return $this->relations[$key];
    }

    // If the "attribute" exists as a method on the model, we will just assume
    // it is a relationship and will load and return results from the query
    // and hydrate the relationship's value on the "relationships" array.
    $camelKey = camel_case($key);

    if (method_exists($this, $camelKey))
    {
        return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key, $camelKey);
    }
}
```

The first condition is `false` because `admin_role` is not an attribute and generally relation does not have a mutator. Fallback to second block

The second block is `false` same as a first condition because you did not use eager loading. Fallback to third condition.

In the third condition

```
    $camelKey = camel_case($key);

    if (method_exists($this, $camelKey))
    {
        return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key, $camelKey);
    }
```

`$camelKey = camel_case("admin_role"); // "adminRole"`

And `adminRole` is not exists in your model (because you defined `admin_role`) thus `$admin->admin_role()` return `null` and `null` value is not an object.